# Mongoose findOne method inside parent find method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to fetch the restaurant name by the restaurantId given by the order document.

Problem: the Restaurant.findOne() returns a **Promise** that is not resolved. I can't run the find method asynchronously.

```
Order.find({ customerId: userId })
    .exec()
    .then((docs) => {
      res.status(200).json({
        count: docs.length,
        orders: docs.map((doc) => {
          let rest = Restaurant.findOne({ doc.restaurantId }).exec();

          return {
            _id: doc._id,
            restaurantName: rest,
            itemTotal: doc.items.length,
            timestamp: doc.timestamp,
            orderStatus: doc.orderStatus,
          };
        }),
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: You can try to get the output of the Order.find into an array first. Then, iterate the array, to query the Restaurant. Or, you can use an aggregation `$lookup` which returns a result in a single query.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `map` won't allow iterations over promises. It will not wait for the promise to complete and move on to the next iteration. You should use `forof`. Like this:

```js
Order.find({ customerId: userId })
    .exec()
    .then(async (docs) => {
      const orders = [];
      for (const doc of docs) {
        let rest = await Restaurant.findOne({ id: doc.restaurantId }).exec();
        orders.push({
          _id: doc._id,
          restaurantName: rest,
          itemTotal: doc.items.length,
          timestamp: doc.timestamp,
          orderStatus: doc.orderStatus,
        })
      }
      res.status(200).json({
        count: docs.length,
        orders,
      });
    });
```

The other problem in your code is:

```js
let rest = Restaurant.findOne({ doc.restaurantId }).exec();
```

it should be:

```js
let rest = Restaurant.findOne({ id: doc.restaurantId }).exec();
```

Comment: Works like a charm lol.. thanks a lot (had no idea promise doesn't get resolved over map)

Comment: you can upvote the answer and mark the answer as accepted ;)
thanks

Answer (score 1):

A better solution would be to do a $lookup in an aggregate

```
Order.aggregate()
.match({ customerId: userId })
.lookup({
   from: 'restaurants' ,
   localField: 'restaurantId', 
   foreignField: 'id' ,
   as: 'orders', 
})
```

If you need to only show some data from the orders you'll need change to defining a pipeline in the aggregate call and throw a $projection.

This will allow all the database to do all of the work and only do 1 call the database rather than 1 for each order and then one for every single order.